# Constraints for a Linear Model Using Quadprog for Ranges/Limits on Coefficients

Tags: r, linear-regression, quadprog

I'm doing some experimented, and I'm certainly aware why constraining coefficients is rarely needed, but here goes.

In the following data, I have used quadprog to solve a linear model. Note that X1 is simply the intercept.

```
X1 <- 1
X2 <- c(4.374, 2.3708, -7.3033, 12.0803, -0.4098, 53.0631, 13.1304, 7.3617, 16.6252, 27.3394)
X3 <- c(2.6423, 2.6284, 36.9398, 15.9278, 18.3124, 54.5039, 3.764, 19.0552, 25.4906, 13.0112)
X4 <- c(4.381, 3.144, 9.506, 15.329, 21.008, 38.091, 22.399, 13.223, 17.419, 19.87)
X <- as.matrix(cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4))
Y <- as.matrix(c(37.7,27.48,24.08,25.97,16.65,73.77,45.10,53.35,61.95,71.15))
M1 <- solve.QP(t(X) %*% X, t(Y) %*% X, matrix(0, 4, 0), c())$solution
```

The challenge is to subject certain coefficients to constraints. I know that I should be altering the Amet and bvac parameters (according to [Linear regression with constraints on the coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577591/linear-regression-with-constraints-on-the-coefficients)). 
However, I'm not sure how to set it up, so that the following constraints are met.

The output reads 
    [1] 37.3468790  1.2872473 -0.0177749 -0.5988443, where the values would be predicted fitted values of X1, X2, X3 and X4.

Constraints (subject to)…

```
X2 <= .899

0 <= X3 <= .500

0 <= X4 <= .334
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to clarify: You give an expected output *"where the values would be predicted fitted values of X1, X2, X3 and X4"*. I assume you are referring to *estimated* (not fitted) parameter values.**

It's quite straightforward to implement constrained parameters when modelling data in `rstan`. `rstan` is an R interface to `Stan`, which in turn is a probabilistic programming language for statistical Bayesian inference.

Here is an example based on the sample data you provide.

1. First, let's define our model. Note that we constrain parameters `beta2`, `beta3` and `beta4` according to your requirements.

   ```
   model <- "
   data {
       int<lower=1> n;   // number of observations
       int<lower=0> k;   // number of parameters
       matrix[n, k] X;   // data
       vector[n] y;      // response
   }

   parameters {
       real beta1;                                                  // X1 unconstrained
       real<lower=negative_infinity(), upper=0.899> beta2;          // X2 <= .899
       real<lower=0, upper=0.5> beta3;                              // 0 <= X3 <= 0.5
       real<lower=0, upper=0.334> beta4;                            // 0 <= X4 <= 0.334
       real sigma;                                                  // residuals
   }

   model {
       // Likelihood
       y ~ normal(beta1 * X[, 1] + beta2 * X[, 2] + beta3 * X[, 3] + beta4 * X[, 4], sigma);
   }"
   ```
2. Next, we fit the model to your sample data.

   ```
   library(rstan)
   rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
   options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
   df <- cbind.data.frame(Y, X)
   fit <- stan(
       model_code = model,
       data = list(
           n = nrow(df),
           k = ncol(df[, -1]),
           X = df[, -1],
           y = df[, 1]))
   ```
3. Finally, let's print parameter estimates in a tidy way

   ```
   library(broom)
   tidy(fit, conf.int = TRUE)
   ## A tibble: 5 x 5
   #  term  estimate std.error conf.low conf.high
   #  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
   #1 beta1   29.2      6.53   16.9        42.8
   #2 beta2    0.609    0.234   0.0149      0.889
   #3 beta3    0.207    0.138   0.00909     0.479
   #4 beta4    0.164    0.0954  0.00780     0.326
   #5 sigma   16.2      5.16    9.42       29.1
   ```

   We can also plot parameter estimates including CI.

Note that parameter estimates are consistent with the imposed constraints.

[image]

Comment: Super helpful. I was able to scale this approach to the full dataset and list of constraints. I am getting an error about a C++ compiler not being install - something that I have tried to install but never seems to work.